# Getting WindowsIdentity in my WCF Web Service

Tags: wcf, web-services, https, windows-identity

I took over code from a developer that is no longer with us. It's a WCF web service that was originally using a passed in username, but we need it to use the WindowsIdentity instead.

```
string identity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name;
```

That code ends up returning an empty string. I'm using a secure (wsHttpSecure) binding so ServiceSecurityContext.Current isn't null or anything. I've been searching for a solution for a day and haven't found anything yet.

Because I'm new to WCF I'm not sure what other information will be relevant. Here are the enabled authentication settings for the web service in IIS:

```
Anonymous Authentication - Enabled
Windows Authentication - Enabled
```

And here's the web.config for the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\instanceNameHere;Initial Catalog=default;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings configSource="appSettings.config" />
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\ServiceLogs\WebServiceLog.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.web>
        <trace enabled="true" />
        <membership defaultProvider="XIMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="XIMembershipProvider" type="LolSoftware.MiddleTier.BusinessLogic.XIMembershipProvider"
      applicationName="LolWebService"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client />
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <behaviors configSource="behaviors.config" />
        <bindings configSource="bindings.config" />
        <services configSource="services.config" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
            <remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0"/>
            <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0"/>
            <add name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
            <add name="svc-ISAPI-4.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
            <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As well as bindings.config:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpSecure">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="wsHttp">
        <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Behaviors.config:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" />
            <serviceCredentials>
                <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="XIMembershipProvider"/>
            </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <!-- -->
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <!-- -->
</behaviors>
```

Service.config:

```
<services>
    <service name="LolSoftware.MiddleTier.WebService.LolWebService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="LolWebService_WSHttpEndpointSecure" contract="LolSoftware.MiddleTier.Interfaces.ILolWebService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpSecure"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get `WindowsIdentity` on the service you must use Windows authentication instead of `UserName` authentication. Be aware that Windows authentication works only for windows accounts in your domain. You should change your IIS configuration and disable anonymous access. Then change `wsHttpBinding` configuration to:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpSecure">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
        </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

You don't need ASP.NET compatibility to use Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the standard ASP.NET methodology, you need to set ASP.NET compatibility to true:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

That would be the first line of attack, if you are hosting the service in IIS, of course. There are other ways to get identity, but this should work for you.

Comment: Is using ASP.NET compatibility the only way to get the WindowsIdentity?